# How to stream audio from iOS to IIS web server

Tags: ios, audio, iis-7

I'd like to stream audio from multiple iOS clients to a central Windows server running IIS 7 for further processing. IIS Media Services seems to be the solution for the opposite problem, of distributing audio from IIS, are there existing libraries for streaming audio to IIS? Or do I have to write, say a WCF TCP service myself? (I'll need to send status messages back to the client, so duplex TCP seems the way to go.)

Comment: So far I've not seen anything specific for this problem, so I'm going with TCP and http://ilbcnet.codeplex.com/ for now. If there is a performance problem, I'll explore [RTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) in greater depth.